# Having an observable the same content as another one with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observable named `packing` which contains a bunch of properties. One of them is an observableArray named `isotopes`

```
packing
 - description
 - type
 - ...
 - isotopes
    - name
    - weight
```

I would like to create a separate observable to have the same content as packing.isotopes. This mus be dynamic so whenever something is added/removed from `packing.isotopes` this should be also added/removed inside `mycopy`.

I already try:

```
var mycopy = ko.computed(function () { return packing.isotopes; });
```

But it doesn't work. `mycopy` is *undefined*.

Any idea?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

Below is my code:

```
define(function (require) {
    ...
    var mycopy = ko.computed(function () { return packing.isotopes; });

    var activate = function (routeData) {
        var idTran = parseInt(routeData.idTran);
        var idPack = parseInt(routeData.idPack);

        var promise = (idPack == -1) ? // -1 --> create a new empty itinerary
                        ctxTransport.createPackingDetailTransport(idTran, packing) : 
                        ctxTransport.getPackingById(idPack, packing); 

        return promise
              .then(ctxTransport.getTransportById(idTran, transport))
              .fail(somethingWrong); 

        function somethingWrong(error) {
            var msg = 'Error retreiving data. ' + error.message;
            logError(msg, error);
            throw error;
        }
    }

    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        canDeactivate: canDeactivate,
        resource: resource,
        transport: transport,
        packing: packing,
        mycopy: mycopy,
        ...
    };
}
```

Comment: In theory this should work. But because you haven't posted your complete code I can only asume that you have some scoping problems. So inside your computed `packing` is not defined... Please post a more complate example where you also have the `packing` definition!

Comment: I updated my question to show you my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computed observables should track other observables, but you have not any observable call inside. Seems that you don't need `computed` ever.

```
var mycopy = packing.isotopes;
```